# Can not `ssh-add` publickey, in spite of excuted the `eval 'ssh-agent -s'`

Tags: git, ssh, cygwin

I tried add the `eval 'ssh-agent -s'`, then `ssh-add` publickey, but still not work.

```
peter@peter-PC /cygdrive/e/Ti02
$ eval 'ssh-agent -s'
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-G6me31Q1Onsv/agent.2122; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=2123; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 2123;

peter@peter-PC /cygdrive/e/Ti02
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

peter@peter-PC /cygdrive/e/Ti02
$
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrong apostrophs: `'`. Use backticks: ``:

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
```

or `$()`:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
```